# Using multiple databases with a single Flask web server

Tags: python, sql, mongodb, flask, nosql

For my project, I want to use a relational database to store user information such as id numbers, system access level, usernames, emails, phone numbers etc. Additionally I wish to use a non-relational database to store files such as images, pdfs, videos and audio recordings posted by users.

I'm fairly new to database technology and back end development so I'm not sure if this design is the most ideal, however, if it is, I want to know if it's possible and are there guides out there to help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend staying away from storing those types of files in a database. That really is what file systems or storage systems like AWS's S3 are for. Having something like:

File: ".../s3/cats/mycrazycat.jpg"

in the database would very often be more efficient than storing the data *inside* the database. You could add tags to the information as well to assist with searching.

While it will really come down to your use case, I'm a strong believer that files should be stored in a file system and **not** in a database.